# How to drop rows based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find:

1. data not found in provider, but found in accounting,
2. data found in accounting, but not in provider
3. data found in both, accounting and provider, but the amounts do not match.

To accomplish this I have to use three provided tables **Accounting**, **Helper**, **Provider**
First I join **Accounting** with **Helper** on invoice.
Then I join it with **Provider** on toID.
After merge inner join I have a table which in this case creates two unnecessary records.

Accounting table looks like:

| doc_nr | amount | invoice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | -9.17 | i1 |
| a2 | 9.17 | i1 |

Helper table:

| toID | invoice |
| --- | --- |
| toid1 | i1 |

Provider table:

| toID | tID | DATE | tAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| toid1 | t1 | 2021-01-18 | 9.17 |
| toid1 | t2 | 2021-01-19 | -9.17 |

After joining three tables using **merge inner** join I got a table:

| doc_nr | amount | invoice | toID | tID | tAmount | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | -9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t1 | 9.17 | 2021-01-18 |
| a1 | -9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t2 | -9.17 | 2021-01-19 |
| a2 | 9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t1 | 9.17 | 2021-01-18 |
| a2 | 9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t2 | -9.17 | 2021-01-19 |

**Expected result** should be only **2** records instead of 4:

| doc_nr | amount | invoice | toID | tID | tAmount | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | -9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t2 | -9.17 | 2021-01-19 |
| a2 | 9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t1 | 9.17 | 2021-01-18 |

Can't think of a way how to filter the table to get expected results.

Tried **dropping duplicates** based on **doc_nr**, but results gives:

| doc_nr | amount | invoice | toID | tID | tAmount | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | -9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t2 | -9.17 | 2021-01-19 |
| a2 | 9.17 | i1 | toid1 | t2 | -9.17 | 2021-01-18 |

It should have different **tID**; **doc_nr** and **amount** match **tAmount**.
After join it seems it duplicates **doc_nr** creating it with other`s **doc_nr** and **tID**.

Any ideas on how to clean these duplicating rows and reach the expected result?

Comment: how are you deciding which value should be returned in the tID, tAmount and Date columns?

Comment: based on records in table which consists of doc_nr, amount, invoice and is joined wither helper data on invoice. Helper data gives toID to match records on provider table which has same toID, but different tID.

Comment: I think you might need to share samples of the tables you're using to generate these results, because in your second table the rows aren't duplicates as the values differ in the tID, tAmount and Date columns. It's difficult to understand the logic of what you want

Comment: Updated. Provider tables has duplicates toID with different tID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> df.assign(x=df['amount'].eq(df['tAmount']).cumsum()).replace(0, np.nan).dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=['doc_nr', 'x']).drop('x', axis=1)
  doc_nr amount invoice   toID tID tAmount        DATE
1     a1  -9.17      i1  toid1  t2   -9.17  2021-01-19
2     a2   9.17      i1  toid1  t1    9.17  2021-01-18
>>>
```

Comment: no, it gives same **tID**, they should be t2 for a1 and t1 for a2

Comment: @A99 What's the logic to that?

Comment: after df.drop_duplicates(subset='doc_nr', keep='last') results match only for a1, but a2 should have tAmount 9.17 and tID t1 like first a2 record on first table

Comment: for me when trying to use df.assign(x=df['amount'].eq(df['tAmount']).cumsum()).replace(0, np.nan).dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=['doc_nr', 'x']).drop('x', axis=1)

gives just an empty df. I implement code on full df

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you want `amount` to match `tAmount`:

> It should have different tID; doc_nr and **amount match tAmount**.

then, you should include also these 2 fields in the second merge statement, as follows:

```
(Accounting.merge(Helper)
           .merge(Provider, left_on=['toID', 'amount'], right_on=['toID', 'tAmount'])
)
```

use the `left_on=` and `right_on=` parameters to include the related 2 merge fields.

**Result:**

```
  doc_nr  amount invoice   toID tID        DATE  tAmount
0     a1   -9.17      i1  toid1  t2  2021-01-19    -9.17
1     a2    9.17      i1  toid1  t1  2021-01-18     9.17
```